Angular - how to use Template variables with new @if syntax
How do you do this in Angular, using the new @if syntax
<ng-container *ngIf="contractSignal().object1?.object2 as templateVariable">
    {{ templateVariable }}
</ng-container>


You can use @if exactly as you used *ngIf structural directive, just add ; after expression and there is no need in ng-container:
@if (contractSignal().object1?.object2; as templateVariable) {
  {{ templateVariable }}
}

BTW, you can play with new control flow on the new Angular site.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284563/215552

I feel stupid. Your comment is valid and works!. My question, was phrased a little incorrectly, and is more like this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78257703/angular-using-template-variables-in-if

accessing deeply nested properties of the object hold by signal is possible and will work within @if ...; as ... block. You can also try signalState from @ngrx/signals, this way each nested property will have its own signal and you can access your property by contractSignal.object1?.object2()
