Angular - using template variables in @if
This only works when I assign 'this.signal().object?.nestedObject' to a variable in a class, in Angular.
Type Narrowing Does Not Work
@if(isTypeA(this.signal().object?.nestedObject)) {
    {{ this.signal().object?.nestedObject.TypeAUniqueProperty }} 
} @else if (isTypeB(this.signal().object?.nestedObject)){
    {{ this.signal().object?.nestedObject.TypeBUniqueProperty }} 
}

Type Narrowing Works
   @if(isTypeA(variable)) {
        {{ variable.TypeAUniqueProperty }} 
    } @else if (isTypeB(variable)){
        {{ varble.TypeBUniqueProperty }} 
    }

Is it possible to assign this.signal().object?.nestedObject to an Angular template variable. It used to be possible with the old ngIf? This elimnates the need to set up variables in the class
UPDATE
I could only do this, by using an outer @if.
@if(this.signal().object?.nestedObject; as templateVariable) {
   @if(isTypeA(templateVariable)) {
      {{ templateVariable.TypeAUniqueProperty }} 
   } @else if (isTypeB(templateVariable)){
    {{ templateVariablet.TypeBUniqueProperty }} 
  }
}


A more efficient way than defining a template variable in @if / ngIf
is to use the new @let syntax introduced in Angular 18:
@let variable = signal().object?.nestedObject;

@if (isTypeA(variable)) {
  {{ variable.TypeAUniqueProperty }}
} @else if (isTypeB(variable)) {
  {{ variable.TypeBUniqueProperty }}
}

See the official documentation.
